# getDecodedBody() not parsing object(raw Graph API response) right

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having strange issue with `Graph API response`. I have a following call to `Graph API`:

```
try{
    $appName=$fb->get('/'.$apid, $apid.'|'.$apsec);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    //echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    //echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getHttpStatusCode();
    if($e->getHttpStatusCode()=='400'){
    echo json_encode('2');
    }
    exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
    }
    $appName=$appName->getDecodedBody();//app data returned as array
```

And this works fine, I get `array` form `object` and I can use it as I like. Now here is the issue. I run almost same code as above, just wanting to retrieve an `url` of `app's icon`:

```
try{
    $appPic=$fb->get('/'.$apid.'/picture', $apid.'|'.$apsec);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getHttpStatusCode();
    if($e->getHttpStatusCode()=='400'){
    echo json_encode('2');
    }
    exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
    }
    $appPic=$appPic->getDecodedBody();
    print_r($appPic);
```

This returns an empty array. But if run the same code in Graph API Explorer, i get the response like this:
[image]

This seems very strange to me, and I can't figure out why this occurs. Please help, I really need this `url` in form of `array`.

**UPDATE:**
I looked a bit more at `Network` part of `Inspect` tool and these two calls DO seem to differ. Here you can see how:

[image]

It seems that first call to `Graph API` uses `Facebook/FacebookResponse` class and second `Facebook/FacebookRequest`. I hit the documentation as soon as I found this and saw that inside the `Facebook/FacebookRequest` there is no such method as `getDecodedBody()`. But when I `var_dump($appPic)` from above code I do get an `array` but empty(of course, after doing `getDecodedBody()`).

**UPDATE**
I also tried this:

```
$url="https://graph.facebook.com/$apid/picture";
$app_icon = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($app_icon);
```

Returns `bool(false)`. When I type this same url in my browser(of course, I enter real app ID, not variable), it shows me the app icon. It seems like `Facebook` doesn't allow `file_get_contents` way of taking data from their servers. I also tried doing same with `cURL`, like this:

```
$url="https://graph.facebook.com/$apid/picture";

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$result=curl_exec($ch);
if(!$result){
echo ('cURL ERROR: '.curl_error($ch));
}
var_dump($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

But when I `var_dump($result);` it returns `bool(true)`, but there is no picture, nor url leading to app picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to retrieve an url to app icon, and it's pretty funny. If you look closer to image that `Inspect` gave me, you will see that `Decoded Body` really is an empty array, God knows why. But `Headers` part of object does have `Location` i.e the url leading to app's icon. So instead of `getDecodedBody()` method I used `getHeaders()` and got array with `Locations` key-value.

Answer (score 0):

You are interpreting the debug information incorrectly. FacebookResponse is a class wrapping the response which you've received from FB as an answer for your request, and your request is packed in FacebookRequest instance.

So FacebookRequest is (probably) your first call, and FacebookResponse is just a response for it.

Comment: First object I got when i did `var_dump($appName)`, second when I did `var_dump($appPic)`. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I disagree with your answer. And that's even not so important, more than this explanation, I would like to get help on how to parse bloody object so I could take url to app's icon.